# Imputing only the numerical values using sci-kit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor

So, I have a DataFrame that contains a mix of both Categorical and Numerical values that is currently `12345` rows by `171` columns.

I have missing values in both the Categorical variable and the Numerical where I would like to impute the values. For the Numerical columns I am doing the following;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('filepath')

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', axis=0)
data = imp.fit_transform(data)
```

I then get the following error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'USD'

This I understand is because I am using sci-kit learns imputer with `strategy='mean'` which is not compatible with Categorical variables. I would rather not have to go through each column and manually pull out the Numerical values so I am looking for a way that I can perform this imputation only on the Numerical columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use panda's [categorical encoding](https://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html) functionality, this can all be handled pretty simply. I however rarely find myself with properly encoded data, and would rather have a robust solution than rely on pure pandas.

Here's what I would do.

```
categorical_columns = []
numeric_columns = []
for c in data.columns:
    if data[c].map(type).eq(str).any(): #check if there are any strings in column
        categorical_columns.append(c)
    else:
        numeric_columns.append(c)

#create two DataFrames, one for each data type
data_numeric = data[numeric_columns]
data_categorical = pd.DataFrame(data[categorical_columns])


from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', axis=0)
data_numeric = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(data_numeric), columns = data_numeric.columns, index=data_numeric.index) #only apply imputer to numeric columns


#you could do something like one-hot-encoding of data_categorical here

#join the two masked dataframes back together
data_joined = pd.concat([data_numeric, data_categorical], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Another thing to consider (which wasn't mentioned in the post) was a situation where you have categorical data expressed in integers (such as clusters or groups). In this case, adding a line to the `for c in data.columns` loop looking for the number of unique values in each column, and potentially adding them to a third list of columns could be useful. If a column is all 0's and 1's, imputing a mean of 0.5 is useless!

Comment: I was myself thinking along the same lines as this answer. Thanks too for the comment above. That is also applicable in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all numeric columns using select_dtypes method:

```
numeric_columns = data.select_dtypes(include='number').columns
imp = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', axis=0)
data[numeric_columns] = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(data[numeric_columns]), columns=numeric_columns)
```